# Set standard default scaling of \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, scaling, sphinx

I am using Sphinx and the plantuml package to include UML diagrams.

The plantuml package for Sphinx generates the following LaTeX code:

```
\includegraphics{%s}
```

Anyways - the diagrams are to big, so what I want is

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{%s}
```

Can I - without patching the plantum package - set a default scale for `\includegraphics` in my LaTeX preamble?

Comment: It's possible to also reduce the size of PlantUML diagrams inside its source with `scale 0.75` as a PlantUML instruction. https://plantuml.com/commons#4252b72e6ebcd4d4

Answer (score 17):

There are two ways.

### First way: set a default value for some keys.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=.75\csname Gin@nat@width\endcsname,keepaspectratio}
```

(the natural width is stored in `\Gin@nat@width`)

### Second way: add `scale=0.75` to the passed options.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\ORIincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\ORIincludegraphics[scale=0.75,#1]{#2}}
```

Comment: First way seems to set the size right, but now one graphic is placed at the end of one page and running over the page border. Second way seems to cause an endless loop: pdflatex is not returning ...

Comment: @Alex Sorry, but without an example of TeX code that shows the bad behaviors it's difficult to help.

Comment: @Alex You can set a limit on the first, using a `\minof` macro. `\def\minof#1#2{\ifdim#1<#2#1\else#2\fi}`. Then `\setkeys{Gin}{width={\minof{.75\csname Gin@nat@width\endcsname}{\linewidth}},keepaspectratio}` will not let big diagrams go wider than `\linewidth`.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to define standard options for `\includegraphics`, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for `scale`. It works for `width` though, which might be an option, too?
See section 4.6 of [`grfguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/grfguide): *Global setting of keys*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=.75\textwidth, height=1cm}
    % in your case, you'd obviously only specify the width
    % I just used height as well for demonstration purposes.

\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example images

\begin{document}\centering

\includegraphics{example-image-16x10}

\includegraphics{example-image-1x1}

\includegraphics{example-image-a4-landscape}

\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}

\end{document}
```

Note that the images originally all have different aspect ratios.

> [image: output]

Comment: Thank you but I think I need scale because I want to have the elements of the UML graphs all to have the same size. And as the UML drawings can be big and small, stretching them to a fixed would change the element's size.

Comment: @Alex I was afraid the situation would be like that. I think I'll still leave the answer up, as it might be helpful for other people with a similar problem. I also pinged David Carlisle, author of `grfguide`, on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6923810#6923810); he might be able to help.

Comment: hmm scale coding looks a bit odd (who did that:-) but you can go `\setkeys{Gin}{width=.75\natwidth,keepaspectratio}` which comes to the same thing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This gives me `! Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@@ewidth ->.75\natwidth ` and `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` (each of them twice per image).