# Set default keepaspectratio=True for includegraphics

Tags: includegraphics

I never need images to stretch. How can I set a default true for keepaspectratio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set standard default scaling of \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83020/set-standard-default-scaling-of-includegraphics)

Comment: you only need to specify keep aspect ratio if you specify height and width, why are you specifying both?

Comment: Werner, that's the post that I based my answer on. @David, I usually use width to specify the image size, but often I need to limit the height. Then, it would be the minimum of the two.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83020/set-standard-default-scaling-of-includegraphics)

```
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}
```